# Multiple Pages in JRXML using iReport for multi page reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I just wanted to know does iReport/JRXML supports reports which are of multiple pages?  If yes, can you give some reference samples?

I am not asking of a report which will grow when data grows.

I have a static report which contains more than one page to deal with. Each page will have different header, footer & content. Just they need to be part of one single *JRXML*.

Comment: Check out [this stackoverflow answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603155/jasperreports-multi-page-report-with-different-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply tried this and it worked, though some issues are present and may not be working in general case but for my case following code worked.

```
    <break>
          <reportElement x="0" y="211" width="554" height="1"/>
    </break>
```

Thanks.