# How can I create a multi-page PDF report in Jasper/iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want to create a multipage PDF report using *iReport*.

When I'm designing in *iReport* it crosses A4 page size. If I increase page height, it prints out empty space in the page. How can I create a multi-page report?

The resulting report:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your `jrxml` file and the screenshot of report's design you want?

Comment: What do you mean `multi-page` report? JR automatically creates new page

Comment: My jrxml file is almost 3000 lines of code...Multipage means number of pages pdf

Comment: My page width is 800 and height is 1000, I have placed textfileds and subreports in Detail band and Group Footer band as per our requirement. I'm using struts2, when i run my application pdf is generated in 3 pages, but after detail band it's displaying in new page.

Comment: 1) Can you add the screenshots of your report's design (in *iReport*) and the resulting report? 2) What is your question? It is still unclear for me

Comment: see screen shot..https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1m36Wg07GFBUMK9XmS4XP6EO_weB7cbVATEx2VQnwFiw/edit

Comment: In screen shot you can, at end of every page there is a some gap..how do i remove this gap

Comment: Is it another question? The problem in your `jrxml` file

Comment: Please see this answer for multi-page jasper reports book: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603155/jasperreports-multi-page-report-with-different-content/56807631#56807631

Answer (score 2):

I am using bellow code and its works perfect for me. You may also try this code.

```
<detail>
        <band height="802" splitType="Stretch">
        // page 1 design here
        </band>



        <band height="802" splitType="Stretch">
        // page 2 design here
        </band>



        <band height="802" splitType="Stretch">
        // page 3 design here
        </band>


</detail>
```

[image: My actual code output pdf screen shot]

Please Note: i set all margin as 0
[image: i set the page margin as 0]

Answer (score 1):

In common properties of main report there is page setup option. There you provide the page dimensions which you want in your output. Also ignore pagination flag should be set to false